# Reading from multiple queues vs chronicle event loop

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

What is the recommended approach to using chronicle event loop with chronicle queues, e.g. if I want to read from 2 queues - can it be done using event loop? (preferrably with each reader running on it's own thread/core)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `EventLoop` is useful when you want to share multiple readers and other actions in a single thread.
If you want to use a thread each, I would suggest using an `ExecutorService` or a `new Thread`